# Printed Static Footer Overlapping Page Content

Tags: css, printing, footer, sticky-footer

I have a static footer which prints on every printed page (yay) but the page content itself goes to the bottom of the printed page as well creating a content collision.

[image]

I've tried various page margins and footer margins, but ultimately, the page content isn't in a repeating container, so no margining seems to make a substantive difference. If I add a negative bottom margin to the footer and increase the page bottom margin, the footer is just cut off and restarted on the next printed page.

```
@page {
    margin-bottom: 30mm;
}
@media only print {
    .report-footer {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0px;
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: -10px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 25px;
        border: dashed 1px red;
        overflow: visible;
    }
}
```

[image]

Is there a practical way to solve this display problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wrap your printable content in a table with a `tfoot`, the `tfoot` will also repeat on each page.  If you give it a height in css, it will create a space at the bottom of each page that your static footer can occupy without collision.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                long printable content...
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>

<div class="report-footer">
    footer content...
</div>
```

with the following CSS

```
tfoot td {
    height: 30px;
}

.report-footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 20px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: solid 1px #ccc;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

[image]

Comment: This answer does not for both header and footer on every page at the same time. I mean when I use also thead for header, this is a big mess in the page and content has still overlap with footer. So do you have any suggestion for this?